# Why does this https? and (|en) regex not work?

Tags: regex

I want to run this code both on http and https. And also with and without the part en. Where do I go wrong?

```
RegExp(/https?:\/\/(myzcloud.me|myzcloud.pro)\/(|en)\/album\/[0-9]+\/[\-_a-zA-Z0-9]+/);
```

It should work on all of them:

```
https://myzcloud.me/en/album/551610/mya
http://myzcloud.me/en/album/551610/mya
https://myzcloud.me/album/551610/mya
http://myzcloud.me/album/551610/mya
```

Comment: You probably wanted `(en\/)?`

Comment: [`/https?:\/\/mysite\.(me|pro)\/(en\/)?album\/\d+\/[a-zA-Z\d_-]+/`](https://regex101.com/r/Od70Qw/1)

Answer (score 1):

**You can use this and you will get your 4 URLs:**

```
/https?:\/\/myzcloud\.(me|pro)\/(en\/)?album\/\d+\/[a-zA-Z\d_-]+/g
```

You can see your code working in [Here](https://regex101.com/r/Od70Qw/4).

Comment: What about `https://myzcloud.pro/en/album/123/a`? Your regex doesn't match.

Comment: I have again edited my regex. Please check it. You will have your answer in the link: https://regex101.com/r/Od70Qw/4

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
/https?:\/\/(myzcloud\.(?:me|pro))\/(en\/)?album\/\d+\/[-\w]+/
```

If you need to match the whole string, add `^` at the start and `$` at the end:

```
/^https?:\/\/(myzcloud\.(?:me|pro))\/(en\/)?album\/\d+\/[-\w]+$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gE4QkM/1)

**NOTES**

- All literal dots in the pattern that are outside character classes must be escaped
- `(myzcloud.me|myzcloud.pro)` = `(myzcloud\.(?:me|pro))`, no need to repeat identical parts of the pattern
- **The culprit!** Your `\/(|en)\/` matches `en` optionally, but if it is missing, the pattern expects `//` to appear in the string. One `/` must be moved to the group, but in JS, it makes sense to just use an optional group, `(en\/)?`.

Comment: The first example worked on https://myzcloud.me/en/album/551610/mya only and the second code worked on https://myzcloud.me/album/551610/mya only.

Comment: @seamoonx [**WORKED ON BOTH**](https://regex101.com/r/gE4QkM/2)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're looking to match the following formats:

```
http://myzcloud.me/album/123/a
https://myzcloud.pro/en/album/123/a
```

Then the `(|en)\/` part of your regex won't match either result.
Instead, you're likely looking for `(en\/)*`:

As:

```
/https?:\/\/(myzcloud.me|myzcloud.pro)\/(en\/)*album\/[0-9]+\/[\-_a-zA-Z0-9]+/
```

This can be seen working **[here](https://regex101.com/r/vwV406/1/)**.

Comment: Your example worked on:https://myzcloud.me/album/123/a but not on http://myzcloud.pro/en/album/123/a Any suggestios?

Comment: Your second code worked for myzcloud.pro/en/album/123/a but not for myzcloud.me/album/123/a